# What is the right phrases verb? So many or such

Tags: word-choice, grammar

She is very glamorous. She always wears so many or such  nice dresses.

Comment: Both sound right, there are slight subtleties in meaning, but I can't think now what they might be.

Comment: Hello, Chandima. Because 'dresses' is a count noun usage here, you can't use 'so much'. But using 'so many' after 'always' really implies that she wears lots at a time. But you're not comparing like with like; 'such' is an intensifier not a quantifier.

Comment: There is no phrasal verb here. "so many" modifies the noun "dresses", and is distinct from the verb "wears".

Answer (score 1):

> She always wears so many nice dresses

could imply that she wears more than one dress simultaneously.

Whereas you don't get that implication when you use

> She always wears such nice dresses.

If you want to use "so many", a possibility could be:

> She has so many nice dresses.